# isinstance failing on same class types

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-ads-api

Can anyone help make sense of this?

Using google python sdk as an example, according to Google retry policy (https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/storage/latest/retry_timeout):

```
from google.api_core import exceptions
from google.api_core.retry import Retry

_MY_RETRIABLE_TYPES = (
   exceptions.TooManyRequests,  # 429
   exceptions.InternalServerError,  # 500
   exceptions.BadGateway,  # 502
   exceptions.ServiceUnavailable,  # 503
)

def is_retryable(exc):
    return isinstance(exc, _MY_RETRIABLE_TYPES)

my_retry_policy = Retry(predicate=is_retryable)
```

Why does the following occur when testing `is_retryable`?

```
exceptions.TooManyRequests==exceptions.TooManyRequests -> True
is_retryable(exceptions.TooManyRequests) -> False 
is_retryable(429) -> False 
is_retryable(exceptions.TooManyRequests.code) -> False
is_retryable(exceptions.TooManyRequests.code.value) -> False
```

Comment: `429` is not an exception.  I don't know what those `code` and `code.value` attributes hold, but they're obviously not exceptions either.

Comment: Are you sure you're not looking for `exc in _MY_RETRIABLE_TYPES`?  What is `exc`?

Comment: correct, but how does `exceptions.TooManyRequests` not satisfy since it is in _MY_RETRIABLE_TYPES?

Comment: @FrankYellin exc is the exception type being passed.

Comment: The exceptions are subclasses of `Exception` that *represent* various HTTP status codes, not `int`-valued variables.

Comment: `is_retryable(exceptions.TooManyRequests())` would return true; you need to pass an *instance* of one of the exception types, not the type itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your tuple consists of a number of *types*. A type is not an instance of itself, nor is it an "alias" of any kind for an integer value. You need to pass an *instance* of one of the types to `is_retryable`.

```
>>> is_retryable(exceptions.TooManyRequests())
True
```